# Sum function Issue in select Query

Tags: sql, sql-server

In the below query i want to sum the approved qty of BatchReleaseSourceProductDetails between particular date range of a product based on maximum version.I tried but i can't able to get the result.pls help me to do this.

Table BatchReleaseSourceProductDetails :

```
BatchReleaseSourceProductDetailID  |BatchReleaseID |SourceProductID|ApprovedQty|CreatedOn|VersionID
1|10|15|10|21-02-2015|0
1|10|15|15|21-02-2015|1
```

Table 2:
BatchRelease:

```
BatchReleaseID|LocationID
10|1

The result should be 15 for date range 21-02-2015 and 21-02-2015

    SELECT @nSouceProductQuantity = Isnull(Sum(Isnull(ApprovedQuantity, 0.0)), 0.0)
FROM   BatchReleaseSourceProductDetails BRSD
       LEFT OUTER JOIN BatchRelease BR
                    ON BR.BatchReleaseID = BRSD.BatchReleaseID
WHERE  ( SourceProductID = @i_ProductID
         AND BR.LocationID = @i_LocationID
         AND Cast(BRSD.CreatedOn AS DATE) >= @i_StartDate
         AND Cast(BRSD.CreatedOn AS DATE) <= @i_EndDate
         AND BRSD.VersionID = (SELECT Max(VersionID)
                               FROM   BatchRelease
                               WHERE  SourceProductID = @i_ProductID
                                      AND BR.LocationID = @i_LocationID
                                      AND Cast(BRSD.CreatedOn AS DATE) >= @i_StartDate
                                      AND Cast(BRSD.CreatedOn AS DATE) <= @i_EndDate) )
```

Comment: What is wrong with the result of your query?

Comment: I want to get sum of approved qty  between particular data range of a particular product based on maximum verison and location

Comment: I think you're going to need to post sample data and desired result.   It looks to me like your query does what you want.

Comment: It looks like that is what your query is doing. Remember we can't see your screen, have no idea what your tables, data or project is like. All we know if what you post which in this case so far is just a query against unknown tables with unknown data producing unknown results for an unknown project.

Comment: @Sean Lange See my edited Question

Comment: @Tab Alleman See my edited Question

Comment: It looks like your query should return 15 for the sample data.   What result are you getting?

Comment: Why is your subquery select MAX(VersionID) from BatchRelease?   In your sample data, there is no VersionID column in the BatchRelease table.   Is that the problem?

Comment: Can you include the variables you have declared?

Comment: @Tab Alleman i am getting 0 versionID is in BatchReleaseSourceProductDetails

Answer (score 0):

Time for some troubleshooting... 
First run the simplest query:

```
SELECT @nSouceProductQuantity = Isnull(Sum(Isnull(ApprovedQuantity, 0.0)), 0.0)
FROM   BatchReleaseSourceProductDetails BRSD
```

Get something back other than 0?  If not fix the issue (do that for each step until you have the results you want).  Done? Good, move on:

```
 SELECT @nSouceProductQuantity = Isnull(Sum(Isnull(ApprovedQuantity, 0.0)), 0.0)
 FROM   BatchReleaseSourceProductDetails BRSD
       LEFT OUTER JOIN BatchRelease BR
           ON BR.BatchReleaseID = BRSD.BatchReleaseID
```

Get something back other than 0?  Good, move on:

```
SELECT @nSouceProductQuantity = Isnull(Sum(Isnull(ApprovedQuantity, 0.0)), 0.0)
FROM   BatchReleaseSourceProductDetails BRSD
       LEFT OUTER JOIN BatchRelease BR
                    ON BR.BatchReleaseID = BRSD.BatchReleaseID
WHERE  SourceProductID = 15
```

Get something back other than 0?  Good, move on:

```
SELECT @nSouceProductQuantity = Isnull(Sum(Isnull(ApprovedQuantity, 0.0)), 0.0)
FROM   BatchReleaseSourceProductDetails BRSD
       LEFT OUTER JOIN BatchRelease BR
                    ON BR.BatchReleaseID = BRSD.BatchReleaseID
WHERE  SourceProductID = 15
         AND BR.LocationID = 1
```

Get something back other than 0?  Good, move on:

```
SELECT @nSouceProductQuantity = Isnull(Sum(Isnull(ApprovedQuantity, 0.0)), 0.0)
FROM   BatchReleaseSourceProductDetails BRSD
       LEFT OUTER JOIN BatchRelease BR
                    ON BR.BatchReleaseID = BRSD.BatchReleaseID
WHERE  SourceProductID = 15
         AND BR.LocationID = 1
         AND Cast(BRSD.CreatedOn AS DATE) >= '21-02-2015'
```

Get something back other than 0?  Good, move on:

```
SELECT @nSouceProductQuantity = Isnull(Sum(Isnull(ApprovedQuantity, 0.0)), 0.0)
FROM   BatchReleaseSourceProductDetails BRSD
       LEFT OUTER JOIN BatchRelease BR
                    ON BR.BatchReleaseID = BRSD.BatchReleaseID
WHERE  SourceProductID = 15
         AND BR.LocationID = 1
         AND Cast(BRSD.CreatedOn AS DATE) >= '21-02-2015'
         AND Cast(BRSD.CreatedOn AS DATE) >= '21-02-2015'
```

Get something back other than 0?  Good, move on:

```
SELECT @nSouceProductQuantity = Isnull(Sum(Isnull(ApprovedQuantity, 0.0)), 0.0)
FROM   BatchReleaseSourceProductDetails BRSD
       LEFT OUTER JOIN BatchRelease BR
                    ON BR.BatchReleaseID = BRSD.BatchReleaseID
WHERE  SourceProductID = 15
         AND BR.LocationID = 1
         AND Cast(BRSD.CreatedOn AS DATE) >= '21-02-2015'
         AND Cast(BRSD.CreatedOn AS DATE) >= '21-02-2015'
         AND BRSD.VersionID = 1
```

If everything has worked til this point, the problem is either in your subquery or your variables.  Troubleshoot them in the same way.  For the subquery make it super simple then gradually add in the WHERE clauses until you have the full query back.  After that, when you are here:

```
SELECT @nSouceProductQuantity = Isnull(Sum(Isnull(ApprovedQuantity, 0.0)), 0.0)
FROM   BatchReleaseSourceProductDetails BRSD
       LEFT OUTER JOIN BatchRelease BR
                    ON BR.BatchReleaseID = BRSD.BatchReleaseID
WHERE  SourceProductID = 15
         AND BR.LocationID = 1
         AND Cast(BRSD.CreatedOn AS DATE) >= '21-02-2015'
         AND Cast(BRSD.CreatedOn AS DATE) >= '21-02-2015'
         AND BRSD.VersionID = (SELECT Max(VersionID)
                           FROM   BatchRelease
                           WHERE  SourceProductID = 15
                                  AND BR.LocationID = 1
                                  AND Cast(BRSD.CreatedOn AS DATE) >= '21-02-2015'
                                  AND Cast(BRSD.CreatedOn AS DATE) <= '21-02-2015')
```

Start replacing the variables, one at a time, until you find the source of your problem.

Comment: Note that you will have to modify the queries above with (1) real data, and (2) any modifications you make to fix issues as you go along

Comment: What is not working?  I posted several queries to try.

Comment: I have edited your last part of answer (ie) version id taking from BatchReleaseSourceProductDetails .The maximum versioid for each batchreleaseid should be taken. you have taken maximum version id for date range only we should include the batchreleaseid also